# Lazy service drawbacks?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

As of Symfony 2.3 lazy service option has become available using ProxyManager. My question is that is there any drawback to this? It seems like it's perfect to init a service only when you need it but I suspect there must be some drawbacks that make Symfony defaults to "false" by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major drawback of using the lazy loading service is that your service must be linked to the `Container` making your service completely coupled with `Symfony2`

You can use lazy loading services but you **shouldn't use them too often**.